# KL divergence term in VAEs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, latent-variable, kullback-leibler

I was reading the textvae paper (A Hybrid Convolutional Variational Autoencoder for Text Generation). There are some things in the paper that are counter-intuitive to me.

First, "In most cases
the model converges to a solution with a vanishingly
small KL term, thus effectively falling back
to a conventional language model." Which means a model converging to a solution with small KL learns bad latent vectors and essentially is a pure autoencoder. My doubt is, shouldn't small KL term means the model learns good latent vectors, since a solution with small KL term means the latent space is close to the guassian which we want, while keeping the reconstruction error small.

Second dobut is, "the KL term value indicates
how much information the network stores
in the latent vector" Why?

Comment: id like to know as well. arent we trying to minimize the kl loss ? why is having small kl bad ?

Answer (score 2):

KL is a regularizer. Think of traditional regularizers: zero weights would perfectly satisfy it, yet are hardly useful for the task at hand.

Having zero-ish $\text{KL}(q(z|x) \mid\mid p(z))$ means that $q(z|x) \approx p(z)$ and hence does not depend on $x$, and thus it **does not contain any information** about $x$ the generative model (the decoder) is asked to reconstruct.